# How can I add fields to forms programmatically in dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I can create entity fields programmatically by using the metadata service of the MS CRM 2013. Now I want to add that field to a form programmatically. It should be hidden. How can I do that? Is that possible at all?

Thanks and Cheers,

Arne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if its supported or not but it is overly complicated andnot going to be easy. We will have to get familiar with [Form XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc906202.aspx).

Check this [Link](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a2acbfb-1ae1-4709-892f-73b0742ccf32/manipulating-forms-programmatically) as well.

happy codding :)